# For each statement not being executed in a While statement?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to do a for each statement inside a while statement and it is not executing my code within the for each statment. I am assuming "value" is not being assigned somehow?

```
cmd = New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = Con
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Physician First Name], [Physician Last Name], [Recipient Primary Business Street Address Line 1], [Recipient City], [Recipient State], [Recipient Zip Code], Notes_ConsultingFee, [Total Amount of Payment]  FROM tblData WHERE ReferenceNumber = @ReferenceNumber"
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ReferenceNumber", (ReferenceTextBox.Text)))
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

While reader.Read()
    For Each value As Object In reader

        Dim firstName = reader.GetString(0)
        Dim LastName = reader.GetString(1)
        Dim Address = reader.GetString(2)
        Dim City = reader.GetString(3)
        Dim State = reader.GetString(4)
        Dim Zip = reader.GetString(5)
        Dim Notes = reader.GetString(6)
        Dim Amount As Decimal = reader(7)
        Session("PDF") &= firstName & " " & LastName & Environment.NewLine & Address & Environment.NewLine & City & "," & State & " " & Zip & Environment.NewLine & "Consulting Fee Amount: " & Amount & Environment.NewLine & "Notes: " & Notes
    Next
End While
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need the `For Each` loop at all, the `While` loop will iterate through the reader for you, like this:

```
While reader.Read()
    Dim firstName = reader.GetString(0)
    Dim LastName = reader.GetString(1)
    Dim Address = reader.GetString(2)
    Dim City = reader.GetString(3)
    Dim State = reader.GetString(4)
    Dim Zip = reader.GetString(5)
    Dim Notes = reader.GetString(6)
    Dim Amount As Decimal = reader(7)
    Session("PDF") &= firstName & " " & LastName & Environment.NewLine & Address & Environment.NewLine & City & "," & State & " " & Zip & Environment.NewLine & "Consulting Fee Amount: " & Amount & Environment.NewLine & "Notes: " & Notes
End While
```

Comment: thank you, my bad I had some code above that was modifying the reference number before the while statement was being executed.